# How to define two ways of iterate according input

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, iteration

What is the most pythonic form to define two ways of iterating. In example, I have this original code:

```
def f1(cat_gen):
    for (a, b), c in cat_gen:
        if some condition:
            yield (a, b), c
```

**but**, depending on `cat_gen` I would need to iterate in this way:

```
def f1(cat_gen):
    for a, b, c in cat_gen:
        if some condition:
            yield a, b, c
```

Is there a way to change conditionally just `(a, b), c` to `a, b, c` in the `for` statement

Comment: What is the condition that triggers the choice for which method you would need?

Comment: actually depends on caller, i could use a parameter in `f1` to specify that

Comment: `for t in cat_gen: ...; yield t`.

Comment: @chepner in the `if` statement i would need to use `a`, `b` and `c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a function that will evaluate the condition properly:

```
def f1(cat_gen, pred):
    for item in cat_gen:
        if pred(item):
            yield item

f1(flat, lambda a, b, c: ...)
f1(nested, lambda ab, c: ...)
```

Or, flatten the nested tuples before passing the iterable to `f1`:

```
def f1(cat_gen):
    for a, b, c in cat_gen:
        if ...:
            yield a, b, c

f1(map(lambda ab, c: (ab[0], ab[1], c), nested))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define it like this

```
def f1(cat_gen):
    # Figure out how to iterate, store it in condition_to_iterate
    for item in cat_gen:
        if condition_to_iterate:
            (a, b), c = item
        else:
            a, b, c = item
        # Do whatever you need with a, b, c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it as 1 function, with two different return forms (maybe not the cleanest decision but depends on the implementation) you'd want to do something like:

```
def f1(cat_gen, yield_method = 0):
    for a, b, c in cat_gen:
        if some condition:
            if yield_method:
                yield a, b, c
            else:
                yield (a, b), c
```

and just have the user be aware of the modes of return by that second argument.

Comment: what about if `cat_gen` items are of the form (a, b), c?